# Complex number - sum of imaginary part

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

**Question:**

> Let $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$. Then what is the value of $$\sum^{15}_{m=1}\text{Im}(z^{2m-1})$$ at $\theta = 2^o$

Not sure how I should attempt this question. Obviously, as it's only the sum of the imaginary part, it will simply be:
$$\sin \theta + \sin 3\theta + \sin 5\theta + ... + \sin 29\theta$$

Not sure how to proceed from here though.

Comment: Hint: Compute the (complex) sum $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{15}z^{2m-1}$, and only after that, consider its imaginary part.

Comment: @Did Thanks, got that now. I made the mistake of trying to sum the imaginary part from the starting/

Comment: Yes. **Motto to remember:** $e^{i\theta}$ is easier to deal with than $\sin\theta$ (or $\cos\theta$).

Comment: @Did Yes. I see that now. We can apply sum of GP and stuff to $e^{i \theta}$... Much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $$z=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta = e^{i\theta}$$

Now we have to calculate $\Im(S)$ where $$S=\sum^{15}_{m=1}z^{2m-1} =  \sum^{15}_{m=1}e^{i(2m-1)\theta}$$

Now Let $$\displaystyle S=e^{i\theta}+e^{3i\theta}+...........+e^{29i\theta}..................(1)\times e^{2i\theta}$$

So $$S\cdot e^{2i\theta} = e^{i3\theta}+............+e^{i29\theta}+e^{i31\theta}.....(2)$$

So we get $$\displaystyle S = \frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{i31\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} = \frac{1-e^{i30\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}-e^{i\theta}}$$

Now Using $$\bullet\; \cos \theta +i\sin \theta = e^{i\theta}$$ and $$\bullet\; \cos \theta -i\sin \theta = e^{-i\theta}$$

and $$\displaystyle \bullet\;  e^{in\theta} = \cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta.$$

We get $$\displaystyle e^{-i\theta}-e^{i\theta}=-2i\sin \theta$$

So we get $$\displaystyle S = -\left[\frac{1-(\cos 30\theta+i\sin 30\theta)}{2i\sin \theta}\right]=i\left(\frac{1-\cos 30\theta}{2\sin \theta}\right)-\frac{\sin 30\theta}{2\sin \theta}$$

Now We have To Calculate $\Im(S)$  Which is $$\displaystyle \left(\frac{1-\cos 30\theta}{2\sin \theta}\right)$$

Now at $\theta = 2^0\;,$ We get $$\displaystyle \Im(S) = \left(\frac{1-\cos 60^0\theta}{2\sin 2^0}\right)=\frac{1}{4\sin 2^0}$$

Comment: Aha..... So you basically used sum of a GP?

Comment: Yes  Gummy bears .

Comment: Ahh.... Don't know how I missed that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome   Gummy bears .

Answer (score 1):

Let $C=\cos\theta+\cos3\theta+\cos5\theta+...+\cos29\theta$
$S=\sin\theta+\sin3\theta+\sin5\theta+...+\sin29\theta$
$C+iS=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+(\cos3\theta+i\sin3\theta)+...+(\cos29\theta+i\sin29\theta)$
$C+iS=e^{i\theta}+e^{3i\theta}+e^{5i\theta}+...+e^{29i\theta}$
$C+iS=\left\{\frac{e^{i\theta}(e^{30i\theta}-1)}{e^{2i\theta}-1}\right\}=\left\{\frac{(e^{30i\theta}-1)}{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}\right\}=\left(\frac{\cos30\theta+i\sin30\theta-1}{2i\sin\theta}\right)$
Compare real and imaginary parts on both sides:$S=\left(\frac{1-\cos30\theta}{2\sin\theta}\right)$
Put $\theta=2^0$ and you get $S=(1-1/2)/(\sin2^0)=1/(4\sin2^0)$